# Can TableViewCell(s) have different heights?

Tags: ios

As part of a table, is it possible for `TableViewCell` to have different heights?

If, so, how can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `UITableViewDelegate` method :

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you will have to override the following function for your tableview datasource delegates::

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```